# Cordova using the wrong path for "ANDROID_HOME"

Tags: android, bash, cordova

I had built an angular application and wanted to turn it into a native android app using cordova.

I had previously installed `android-sdk` using `apt-get` which was added to by `/usr/lib` folder. I also had installed Android Studio separately who's sdk-tools were located in `~/Android/Sdk`.

Previously, my `$ANDROID_HOME` variable contained path `/usr/lib` but after installation of Android Studio I had changed it to `<myhomedirectory>/Android/Sdk`

Previously, the `android-sdk` tools installed had version 23, which was incompatible with the newer version of gradle, and gave me the following error upon running `cordova run android` (with sudo) in my project:

```
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (23.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.3.0.
Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
```

Followed by the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
     build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3
     platforms;android-28 Android SDK Platform 28
  To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

  Using Android SDK: /usr/lib/android-sdk
```

The Android Studio I installed had tools installed for both API 28 and API 29, but I did not know why it was still giving me this error, until I noticed the last line of this error, which stated that my Android SDK is being fetched from `/usr/lib` (the old directory). I tried checking the environment variables again, sourcing the `~/.bashrc`, as well as logging out but nothing really worked.

I decided to remove the previously installed `android-sdk` and purge the files using `apt` but even then nothing happened.

I even removed the `mobile` folder (the project folder for cordova I created) and even restarted from scratch, but it still gave me the same error.

I am unsure why it is still picking up the wrong path from environment variable, I've even `echo`-ed the variable and the path is the one I set just recently, but cordova for some reason seems to disagree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with the permissions in the cordova project. Had to `sudo chown -R <myproject>`. I first noticed when I tried `sudo cordova requirements` instead of `cordova requirements` (which said I had all requirements installed). I noticed these installations were on user level not on root level, which is why upon sudo it was giving me an error. After `chown`-ing simply run `cordova run android`. You'll no longer have issues.